# Mysterious psaadm process

Tags: linux, plesk

While running 'top' on my server, I noticed a psaadm process that just started popping up. The command is always "/usr/bin/sw-engine-cgi -c /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/php.ini -d auto_prepend_file=auth.php3 -u psaadm." It's only taking about 1-2% of CPU, but I'm not sure why the command keeps repeating. Any insight? I'm a bit of newbie when it comes to servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is the plesk server required for your system. psaadm is the user that runs that process.

Comment: Thanks! I figured this was a pretty dumb question. I'm just not used to seeing it so high up in the processes.